# Lower bound on diameter of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

How is $1+d+d(d-1)+\ldots+d(d-1)^{r-1}<d(d-1)^r$ in the following proof? Here $d$ is the maximum degree of a graph, $n$ is the number of vertices of a graph and $\delta$ is the diameter of a graph.

> **Theorem $\boldsymbol{2.6}$.** Assume $d \geq 3$. Then we have
>   $$\delta > \frac{\log n}{\log(d-1)} -2.$$
>   For a regular graph, we also have
>   $$\gamma < 2 \frac{\log n}{\log(d-1)} +2.$$
>   *Proof.* Let $u$ be a fixed vertex. Then balls around $u$ grow at most exponentially with respect to the radius:
>   $$|B_r(u)| \leq 1+d+d(d-1)+\ldots+d(d-1)^{r-1}<d(d-1)^r.$$

Comment: You might find [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_graph#Bounding_vertices_by_degree_and_diameter) about the *Moore bound* useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: It is $$1+d+d(d-1)+\cdots +d(d-1)^{r-1}=1+{\frac {d \left( d-1 \right) ^{r}}{d-2}}-{\frac {d}{d-2}}$$